# java creational design patterns in swing

Tags: java, design-patterns, swing, jdialog

I have a series of static utility methods of this form:

```
StringBuffer Util.doA(String arg0, String arg1, SomeEnum e);  
StringBuffer Util.doB(String arg0, String arg1);  
StringBuffer Util.doC(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2,String arg3);  
StringBuffer Util.doD(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2,String arg3, AnotherEnum e);  
etc
```

I want to display a JDialog that is created dynamically e.g. via builder or other pattern and once a button is pressed I want the appropriate utility method to be called depending on the type of dialog.
E.g. If JDialog is of `type A` the actionlistener of button should call the `Util.doA` passing as arguments data from the input fields and if JDialog is of `type B` I want the actionlistener of button to call `Util.doB` etc.
Types A, B etc are my custom types. Are not mandatory to be used. I just have them to distinguish between each JDialog.
JDialog of type A differs from JDialog of type B in some of the input fields. But the overall appearance is similar.
Totally there are about 20 types and 20 corresponding util methods.
Is there a standard pattern to this problem I have?
I started extending JDialog so that each custom JDialog creates itself properly and the method of actionlistener calls the appropriate utility method, but I end up with 20 new classes.
So I thought if there is a better approach to this.
Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know about you, but on, e.g. `JDialog A`'s button, when I implement the `actionPerformed()`, I'll call `Util.doA(String arg0, String arg1, SomeEnum e);` and I'll carry on for each JDialog.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman:As mentioned, I did it as you say.But I ended up with 20 new classes being introduced (one for each dialog). I thought that perhaps there was a pattern for this to reduce the classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the corresponding util method inside the 20 types.  If there is any duplication between the types you might be able to move it to a super class.

As to your question, I think this is the optimal approach in your case.  If you have the dialog and util code all in one class and nothing more, then it is clear what that class's purpose is.  It also means that if you need to remove, change, add a new type you are only having to delete one class, modify one class, or create one new class. Keeping all the related code together prevent's  "Shotgun surgery".